# Tomcat7 fails to load server.xml

Tags: tomcat

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to get our app moved from tomcat5 to tomcat7. I finally found this log that gave me a clue but it is very vague. This is what is says:

```
+ /usr/java/bin/java -Dnop -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xmx1g -Xms256m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/software/tomcat-sbox7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.30 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/software/tomcat-sbox7/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start 
Oct 4, 2012 2:13:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /software/tomcat-sbox7/temp
Oct 4, 2012 2:13:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/software/tomcat-sbox7/conf/server.xml]
Oct 4, 2012 2:13:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /software/tomcat-sbox7/temp
Oct 4, 2012 2:13:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/software/tomcat-sbox7/conf/server.xml]
Oct 4, 2012 2:13:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

I dont know why these things are failing to load. Is there a place where I can find a more comprehensive log or maybe you have some ideas I can try to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the common.loader in the app's catalina.properties was:

```
common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib
```

It needed to be:

```
common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this unusual as it is not explained properly, and it is in use a lot. My preference is to go with the Linux installation and then start is standardized with service command:

```
service tomcat7 start
```

If you see the command after this, you see that there is a detailed java application started on the OS level with a lot of parameters, more specific ones as proxy, hostname, path and so on. This I find more appropriate than just running catalina.sh run, where to prevent your problems with directories you have to add parameters with switches for directories, path etc

This approach is also preventing problems with scatered conf, admin and temp directories.

Comment: THANKS! That worked whereas startup.sh/shutdown.sh and catalina.sh start and catalina.sh stop did not, due to missing server.xml!

Answer (score 0):

The best bet are the default logs at $CATALINA_HOME/logs which is by default named catalina.out. If you go to the Tomcat's conf directory, and edit server.xml you can enable the Valve config to print access logs, but that is not going to help you specifically here.

The error here (at a guess) it seems that tomcat config (from the 1st line) that is expecting those directories in /software/tomcat-sbox7/temp to exist and they are not there?  Is this a hosted Tomcat instance?

Answer (score 0):

Such issues more often than not are related to Linux permissions. Specially when you see lines saying -

`'SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /software/tomcat-sbox7/temp'`

and you are sure that this directory exists.

You may like to check which Linux user is used for starting the Tomcat JVMs. Try logging in as that particular user and try to access this particular directory. In my case, that was the problem. Corrected this permission issue and the issue was resolved!